# VBA Range.Find() method not finding anything when the search value is definitely in the range

Tags: excel, vba

I have some string data in a column, and I would like to know where that data occurs in the column. I am using `Range.Find(What, LookAfter, LookIn, LookAt)` to do this. The range is the entire first column (A:A) and the `What` is a string that I would like to find. `LookAfter` is blank, `LookIn` is `xlValues`, `LookAt` is `xlPart`. However, even though the value is definitely there, it is not finding it.

I have even tried just setting the range to just that one cell where I know the value is. The value I am searching for is "INSPECTION DATE", and the value in the cell (`cell.Value2`) is "INSPECTION DATE:" according to the watch I have on the variables. However, the range returned from the `Find` is `Nothing`.
[image: https://i.imgur.com/Z9ISf1L.png] 
[image: https://i.imgur.com/T4np1Su.png].

The code for this function is as follows. The worksheet is a parameter since this method is being called in a loop which loops through each worksheet in the workbook.

```vb
Function ExtractOtherMetadata(ws As Worksheet, metadataCellName As String) As String

    Dim resultCell As Range
    Set resultCell = ws.Range("A3")
    Set resultCell = resultCell.Find(metadataCellName, , xlValues, xlPart)

    Set resultCell = resultCell.Offset(0, 1)

    ExtractOtherMetadata = resultCell.Value2
End Function
```

Unlike other issues of the same nature, this does not seem to be a formatting issue (e.g. looking for a date, or percentage)

Is there somewhere I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you looking for a value inside a range with only one cell? Why not pointing directly to that cell?

Comment: @Damian, I was doing it purely for testing purposes. In my actual "production" case, I use the range "A:A".

Comment: @JohnColeman Do the images I posted help? They show the values that come through in my Watches.

Comment: That string might not be what you think it is, Unicode has a [lot of white space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) characters.  U+00A0 is quite common for example.  Narrow down by searching for "INSPECT" to ensure the basics are working.

Comment: I don't doubt it because I've witnessed it myself mapping fields on converted PDFs. If you have any merged cells, make sure it is completely within your search range.  Merged cells are the devil. If your using a superfluously large range, try narrowing it down. Those were the two changes that ended my problems. Though... "*I have even tried just setting the range to just that one cell where I know the value is.*" Is suspicious.  If it isn't a merged feel then I have to agree that there someone else driving your problem.

Comment: @JohnColeman the OP is using the `xlPart` so it shouldn't matter. Actually I've tried the code and works fine for me. Maybe as Hans pointed, there are blank spaces in the cell or like Profoundly said, is a merged cell.

Comment: A few things you can try...  Type the same string in the same column but a different cell, use a worksheet formula to test is they are equal and use your search macro to see if you pick up the one you just typed.  Copy and paste the problematic cell into several cells in the same column to see if you get any his.  Make sure you don't have a leading apostrophe.  Those apostrophes are as bad as merged cells.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious Yep... You are right. It was a merged cell. It was throwing me off because in the `Value2` for the range, I had: `"INSPECTION DATE:" , Empty`, so I figured just the first cell would be enough. But I did change my test case to A3:B3 and it worked as expected.

Comment: I hate those buggers!!  Glad you got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ProfoundlyOblivious for the solution:

The issue was the fact my search range included merged cells. Since I was only searching in column A (A:A), and the cells were merged over columns A and B, `.Find()` was not picking it up. After changing my range to encapsulate both columns, the search string was found as expected.